# C++ list or vector of any type function

Tags: c++, list, vector

I'm trying to create a function that will accept a `list` or `vector` of any type

```
template <typename T>
void printSomething ( const T& v )
{
    for( T::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

i got this error:

```
error: need ‘typename’ before ‘T:: iterator’ because ‘T’ is a dependent scope
  for( T::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i )
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How would I know that this would be a duplicate, if I don't know that I have to put `typename` before the `iterator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

Yes, do exactly what the error message says.

```
for( typename T::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i )
     ^^^^^^^^
```

The meaning of `iterator` depends on the template parameter, which isn't known until the template is instantiated. So, in the template definition, the compiler doesn't know that it's a type name unless you tell it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'll accept it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
for( T::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i )
```

You should prepend it with typename

```
typename T::iterator i
```

as iterator is dependent on template parameter T...

Answer (score 0):

So your full program will look like this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void printSomething ( const T &v )
{
    for( typename T::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> intV;
    intV.push_back(10);
    intV.push_back(20);
    intV.push_back(30);

    printSomething(intV);

    vector<char> intC;
    intC.push_back('A');
    intC.push_back('B');
    intC.push_back('C');
    printSomething(intC);
}
```